# Extracting day in a new field from a date in Pentaho

Tags: kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a field with a date in yyyy-MM-dd format, I want to extract the day only, for example, if the date is 2014-01-25, I want to have "25" in a new field. I used step "Calculator" is calculation "day of month of date A" but I get 1970-01-01 01:00:00 for all records.
Could someone tell me what might be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you actually have the **Calculator** step, have a **Select Values** step and make sure the date field is Date by explicitly giving the Date data type and specify the format it is currently in.